# Where is the config file in Odoo 10 (Windows+Eclipse IDE)?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to debug Odoo 10 in windows using eclipse and i can't find where is the config file. In previous versions there was a file called 'openerp-server.conf' but i can't find it in Odoo 10.

I am cloning a repo from github : github.com/odoo/odoo.git and there isn't odoo.conf.

Also, I need to know which is the start file to begin with the debug.

thanks..

Comment: am cloning a repo from github : github.com/odoo/odoo.git and there isn't odoo.conf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a file yourself, copy the below code into the file and save the file with `.conf` extension. Ex: `odoo.conf`

```
 [options]
    ; This is the password that allows database operations:
    ; admin_passwd = admin
    db_host = localhost
    db_port = 5433
    db_user = odoo
    db_password = odoo
    xmlrpc_port=1234
    addons_path =F:\Workspace\odoo-10.0-20161005\odoo\addons,F:\Workspace\odoo-10.0-20161005\custom_addons
```

Answer (score 1):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server there u will get odoo.conf file in which

```
[options]
addons_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons
admin_passwd = admin
bin_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\thirdparty
csv_internal_sep = ,
data_dir = C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A\Odoo
db_host = localhost
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = False
db_password = openpgpwd
db_port = 5432
db_sslmode = prefer
db_template = template1
db_user = openpg
dbfilter = 
demo = {}
email_from = False
geoip_database = /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb
http_enable = True
http_interface = 
http_port = 8069
import_partial = 
limit_memory_hard = None
limit_memory_soft = None
limit_request = None
limit_time_cpu = None
limit_time_real = None
limit_time_real_cron = None
list_db = True
log_db = False
log_db_level = warning
log_handler = :INFO
log_level = info
logfile = C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo.log
logrotate = False
longpolling_port = 8072
max_cron_threads = 2
osv_memory_age_limit = 1.0
osv_memory_count_limit = False
pg_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\PostgreSQL\bin
pidfile = None
proxy_mode = False
reportgz = False
server_wide_modules = web
smtp_password = False
smtp_port = 25
smtp_server = localhost
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = False
syslog = False
test_commit = False
test_enable = False
test_file = False
test_report_directory = False
translate_modules = ['all']
unaccent = False
without_demo = False
workers = None
```

this kind of content will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Try here:

Odoo/odoo/debian/odoo.conf

Hope it will help you.

Comment: am cloning a repo from github : https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git and there isn't odoo.conf.

Comment: Updated my answer. Try now

Answer (score 0):

You can add `--save` as script parameter then you should find `openerp-server.conf` next to `odoo.py`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone...

I got the Odoo configuration file for Odoo version 13 docker container.

The location is:

```
/etc/odoo/odoo.conf
```